# How do I turn a string in to a partial class name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to loop over a number of preset strings and use those strings as the class name for third-party API calls.

For example, hardcoded I'd do something like this:

```
Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all
```

But I've got a number of these I need to use as part of generic functions and would like to be able to do something like:

```
class_name = 'BalanceTransaction'
Stripe::class_name.all
```

That obviously doesn't work, but not sure what *would* work.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.1 (so ActiveSupport::Inflector and other modules are indeed available for use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constantize` is what you're looking for.

```
"Stripe::BalanceTransaction".constantize.all
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Answer (score 1):

```
class_name = 'BalanceTransaction'
Stripe.const_get(class_name).all
```